# According to Catholicism, why did God lower Himself so much for the specks of dust like us?

Tags: catholicism, christology, incarnation

St. Paul said, "It is through suffering that we find strength."

St. Augustine said, "My heart is restless until I find abode in You."

And not only that God wanted to feel how humans feel the love with their senses so much that He emptied Himself so He can understand that.

But most humans were not like that.

So why did God lower Himself so much for the specks of dust like us?

Comment: Do you have a source for God wanting to feel how humans love being the reason for the incarnation? If God is omniscient, as Catholicism teaches, he'd know that already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Philippians 2:2-8 (DRB)**
>
> Fulfil ye my joy, that you may be of one mind, having the same charity, being of one accord, agreeing in sentiment. 3 Let nothing be done through contention, neither by vain glory: but in humility, let each esteem others better than themselves: 4 Each one n**ot considering the things that are his own, but those that are other men's.**
>
> 5 **For** let **this mind** be in you, which **was** also **in Christ Jesus:** 6 Who being in the form of God, thought it not robbery to be equal with God: 7 But emptied himself, taking the form of a servant, being made in the likeness of men, and in habit found as a man. 8 He humbled himself, becoming obedient unto death, even to the death of the cross.

Being perfect love itself, He couldn't let humanity perish eternally if there was a way to prevent it, and so He humbled Himself and took on our nature Himself, to provide us with redemption from said inevitable, just fate. Pride not being found in Him at all, He humbled Himself for the sake of love.

> **John 15:13 (DRB)**
>
> Greater love than this no man hath, that a man lay down his life for his friends.
>
> **Mark 10:45 (DRB)**
>
> For the Son of man also is not come to be ministered unto, but to minister, and to give his life a redemption for many.

He loved us so much, seeing in us what we cannot always see, namely, His image in our soul (the image made to reflect the glory of its Maker, not perish), that He wanted if necessary to lay down His life to save us—something not possible in His divine nature, for which reason He elected to become the new Adam.

> **1 Corithians 15:21-22 (DRB)**
>
> For by a man came death, and by a man the resurrection of the dead. And as in Adam all die, so also in Christ all shall be made alive.

Answer (score 1):

If we accept the axiom "God loves us", the answer is clear, because God loves us, and accepting others, regardless of their state, is what love is.

To quote a Disney movie: "People do crazy things when they are in love".

Or to quote St. Paul:

> "Love is patient; love is kind; love is not envious or boastful or arrogant or rude. It does not insist on its own way; it is not irritable or resentful; it does not rejoice in wrongdoing, but rejoices in the truth. It **bears all things**, believes all things, hopes all things, **endures all things**."(1 Corinthians 13:4-7, emphasis mine)